# Karate & JDK Upgrade Eclipse

Tags: karate

Is there an install/configuration guide for Karate 1.4.0?
Specifically, I'm looking for help to upgrade my maven karate cucumber project, from 1.3.1 on java jdk 8 to 1.4.0 on java jdk 11

Comment: I was able to fix the problem I was having, using that thread mostly (essentially creating the cucumber.api.cli main.java class)